# How can i remove xsi:type attribute from xml?

Tags: xml

Acctually i create this xml file using caster

but when this caster generate the xml file it add the xsi:type attribute to my xml file

please help me....

Comment: Some samples of what you're trying to do, and what you're seeing, would be helpful.

Comment: do you mean Castor? (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castor_%28software%29). And yes, not many people will answer questions with 8% accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this helps you.

[How change Castor mapping to remove "xmlns:xsi" and "xsi:type" attributes from element in XML output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007706/how-change-castor-mapping-to-remove-xmlnsxsi-and-xsitype-attributes-from-el)

You may have to use setSuppressXSIType method.