# How change Castor mapping to remove "xmlns:xsi" and "xsi:type" attributes from element in XML output?

Tags: java, xml, mapping, castor

How do I change the Castor mapping

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapping PUBLIC "-//EXOLAB/Castor Mapping DTD Version 1.0//EN"
                         "http://castor.org/mapping.dtd">

<mapping>
    <class name="java.util.ArrayList" auto-complete="true">
        <map-to xml="ArrayList" />
    </class>
    <class name="com.db.spgit.abstrack.ws.response.UserResponse">
        <map-to xml="UserResponse" />
        <field name="id" type="java.lang.String">
            <bind-xml name="id" node="element" />
        </field>
        <field name="deleted" type="boolean">
            <bind-xml name="deleted" node="element" />
        </field>
        <field name="name" type="java.lang.String">
            <bind-xml name="name" node="element" />
        </field>
        <field name="typeId" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <bind-xml name="typeId" node="element" />
        </field>
        <field name="regionId" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <bind-xml name="regionId" node="element" />
        </field>
        <field name="regionName" type="java.lang.String">
            <bind-xml name="regionName" node="element" />
        </field>
    </class>
</mapping>
```

to suppress the `xmlns:xsi` and `xsi:type` attributes in the  element of the XML output?  For example, instead of the output XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<ArrayList>
    <UserResponse xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="UserResponse">
        <name>Tester</name>
        <typeId>1</typeId>
        <regionId>2</regionId>
        <regionName>US</regionName>
    </UserResponse>
</ArrayList>
```

I'd prefer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<ArrayList>
    <UserResponse>
        <name>Tester</name>
        <typeId>1</typeId>
        <regionId>2</regionId>
        <regionName>US</regionName>
    </UserResponse>
</ArrayList>
```

such that the element name implies the `xsi:type`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the Castor Marshaller property `suppressXSIType` to false:

```
Marshaller marshaller = new Marshaller(w);
marshaller.setSuppressXSIType(true);
```

See [Configuring the Marshaller](http://www.castor.org/reference/html/XML%20data%20binding.html#d0e1655) in the [Castor 1.3.1 Reference Documentation](http://www.castor.org/reference/html/index.html).  (Note that *Table 1.10 Marshaller properties* lists only property `suppressNamespaces`, but methods `setSuppressNamespaces()` and `setSuppressXSIType()` both exist in class `Marshaller`.)